# How cast ancestor interface to descendant?

Tags: delphi, interface, casting, multiple-inheritance

In following piece of code:

```
type
    IFoo = interface
    end;

    IFoo<T> = interface(IFoo)
        procedure DoStuff(a: T);
    end;

    TFoo = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo<Integer>, IFoo<string>, IFoo)
        procedure DoStuffInt(a: Integer);
        procedure DoStuffStr(a: string);
        procedure IFoo<Integer>.DoStuff = DoStuffInt;
        procedure IFoo<string>.DoStuff = DoStuffStr;
    end;

procedure TFoo.DoStuffInt(a: Integer);
begin
    Showmessage(a.ToString);
end;

procedure TFoo.DoStuffStr(a: string);
begin
    ShowMessage(a);
end;

var
    iint: IFoo<Integer>;
    istr: IFoo<string>;
    i: IFoo;
begin
    i := TFoo.Create;
    IFoo<integer>(i).DoStuff(123);  // error
    IFoo<string>(i).DoStuff('abc'); // error
end.
```

I want to call DoStuff methods but it doesn't work for way I did it. How cast it correctly?

Details:
Im going to have factory which will produce a IFoo instances and then i will have to cast them to concrete IFoo.

Edited:
For one interface its work fine:

```
type
    IFoo = interface
    end;

    IFoo<T> = interface(IFoo)
        procedure DoStuff(a: T);
    end;

    TFoo = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo<integer>, IFoo)
        procedure DoStuff(a: Integer);
    end;

procedure TFoo.DoStuff(a: Integer);
begin
    Showmessage(a.ToString);
end;

var
    i: IFoo;
begin
    i := TFoo.Create;
    IFoo<Integer>(i).DoStuff(123);
    // curiosity
    IFoo<string>(i).DoStuff('abc'); // it call DoStuff(a: Integer)
```

Comment: I don't think that what you want is possible. A mere cast won't *convert*, and to *convert* you would need a GUID, but that would be problematic for generics. I don't think you can have this kind of polymorphism. You would need two implementing classes (they can have the same base class).

Comment: You don't need multiple implementation classes, a single class can implement multiple interfaces. A mere typecast won't work, since the two interfaces are not related to each other. You need to use [`SysUtils.Supports()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) instead to query one interface from another. But that requires each interface to have a unique guid and a Generic interface cannot have different guides for different values of `T`, so you wouldn't be able to query for `IFoo<Integer>` and `IFoo<string>` separately

Comment: You need to replace `IFoo<T>` with (or at least derive from it) separate interfaces `IFooInteger` and `IFooString`, then they can each have their own guid

Comment: @Remy: But why make things so complicated, if it is much easier to have two implementation classes, only differening in DoStuff. A single class can certainly implement multiple interfaces, but not multiple generic interfaces that only differ in the parametric type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis because sometimes it does make sense to have a single class implement multiple interfaces for performing different kinds of work. And a class can certainly implement multiple types of the same Generic interface. You just can't *query* an object for different types of the same Generic interface since they don't have unique guids. But that is not the only way to use interfaces.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm not a big fan of Generic interfaces, though. An interface is a contract in functionality. Just because two interfaces resemble each other's contracts doesn't necessarily mean they should be declared using a single Generic interface. At least until the compiler supports a way to specialize Generics, so a Generic interface can have different guids for different types of `T`.

Comment: @Remy: hmmm... I think that,say, an IList<T> or IEnumerator<T> do make sense. They offer the same functionality for containers containing a T. I can also imagine generic interfaces for certain algorithms. So they make sense, but are sometimes overused.

Comment: Im implementing simple event/eventHandler library. I wanted allowed user to create one class which handle multiple events i.e. for log them(Saga pattern from DDD).

Comment: @aQuu Well, you can do that easily enough just by using function overloading. It also make the code easier to read and implement.

Comment: Indeed. Generics simply don't fit here. Overloaded methods are what you need.